# Cryptic clues for fun

Tags: cryptic-clues

Hey some cryptic crossword clues to munch on

1) Information regarding loan in Dubai perhaps (7)

2) Some men deserve death (3)

3) Picture facing the past? (4,2,3,6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1

> EMIRATE (EMI = equated monthly instalment, hence EMI RATE; the Emirate of Dubai is one of the United Arab Emirates)

2

> END (contained in "mEN Deserve"; means death, near enough)

3

> BACK TO THE FUTURE, I think ("picture" in the clue presumably means movie)

Comment: all correct but can you provide anno too